# How to implement Google Login for an iOS Application?

Tags: ios, google-signin

I am new to iOS development... I want to implement the Google+ Login in my app but now days Google accepts one account Login process... How to implement it using cocoa pods?

Comment: Google is fairly well documented for the API's it provides. To best utilize SO, you're going to have to read the relevant Google docs, try to implement a solution, and post when you have a specific problem with your existing implementation.